# Conditional statements in HTML to rule out non-mobile devices

Tags: mobile, conditional-statements, clickable, device, statements

well i've made a responsive website which handles well in mobile devices. Now there are some Phonenumbers on the website which my cliënt would like to be clickable on any Phone so the visitor can call directly. I found that making a link of the phonenumbers works like so:

```
<a href="tel:003164646464">make a call</a>
```

This triggers mobilephones to call the number. But it also triggers the webbrowser on any other device to follow the link, which results in "page can't be found" 
I'm looking for a good anwser to tackle this problem. I've been searching for a while now but i'm getting a bit tired and frustrated.
I think i've come with a solution but i don't excactly know how to put this in the html.
There are several ways to conditional comment browsers in html. If i could do this with the link part and rule it out:

```
<!--[if any **none mobile** webrowsers: don't read:]><a href="tel:003164646464">003164646464</a>
```

And all mobile browsers read the link.
It seems to me, that this is the most easy way to do this, but i could be wrong...
I hope that someone can give me any pointers, I really appreciate your idea's and help!

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to achieve this. You can use different approaches depending how accurate you want to be:

1. [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net) - most accurate, allows to check user-agent and get browser / device capabilities
2. You can try parsing user-agent by your own detecting OS - check this answer [Detecting a mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/javascript-solution-to-detect-mobile-browser)
3. Use css media queries to target devices with small screen

Unfortunately there is no silver bullet for this (at least I don't know one).

Comment: Well, you're probably wrigth to do it with media queries. Show/hide a div with the link in it, seems to be the most easy way to fix this.